# Parse.com Hosting: How to view website statistics

Tags: parse-platform, hosting

I have a website hosted with parse, http://skipch.at

Am I able to view the traffic statistics for this site using the online data browser?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be a programming question.

Comment: My bad, where should i post it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Analytics makes this really easy - apologies for the novice question